# Bootstrap - Having Navbar in the top of the page then center the form

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have this page which was built by using Bootstrap (picture). Is there any method to have a Navbar at the top of the page which has a logo and several links such as About Us, Security, Sign In, Sign Up, then center the Login Form in the middle of the page and having the page work properly in any screen devices? Thank you for your help

[image: This is the Login Page]

Login.js

```
<div className="Login">
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="email">
      <Form.Control
        autoFocus
        type="email"
        value={email}
        placeholder="Please enter your email"
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="password">
      <Form.Control
        type="password"
        value={password}
        placeholder="Please enter your password"
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Form.Group>
    <a href="forget.html" className="forgot-password">
      Forgot Password?
    </a>
    <Button block size="lg" type="submit" disabled={!validateForm()}>
      Sign In
    </Button>
    <Button block size="lg" type="submit">
      Sign Up
    </Button>
  </Form>
</div>
```

Login.css

```
body {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
background: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/f0328534-9c08-4f7a-867f-48d6314fffae%2Fchewy-DR6wPYR2DRc-unsplash.jpg?v=1603075265987")
  no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
.Login {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.Login form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 320px;
}


}
  
  Form {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 24px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
  
  Form h2 {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #555555;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 47px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
  
  .form-control {
    height: 54px;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
  }
  
  .forgot-password {
    padding: 2px;
  }
  
  .Login button {
    margin-top: 24px;
    background-color: #555555;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  
  .Login button:hover {
    background: #a64bf4;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #00dbde, #fc00ff);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #00dbde, #fc00ff);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #00dbde, #fc00ff);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00dbde, #fc00ff);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
  }
  
  .Login form label {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
```

Comment: Can you also share your navbar and this main page where you have putted Login Component in codesandbox ?

Comment: I haven't had the navbar yet, this is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-ellis-x0sbv?file=/src/containers/Login.js

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you should remove the `img` from body tag. I believe that when you redirect the user to different page you want to show different content, this image is only for the Login page.
In your App.js, your code should be like this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar /> // here you can add your navigation bar component
      <div className="App">
        <Login />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Remove your image from the body tag and in the App.css, you code should be like this:

```
.App {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);  // here minus the height of your navbar component, for my case I took 50px
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/f0328534-9c08-4f7a-867f-48d6314fffae%2Fchewy-DR6wPYR2DRc-unsplash.jpg?v=1603075265987")
    no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Now in your Login.js, a simple way to make the in the center of the image is like this:

```
  .Login {
    /* padding: 60px 0; */
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

For the responsive, you have to look at the grid system of boostrap or you can get your hands dirty using the `media-queries`.